# Meta tag Og:Image not showing image

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

I am having problem with getting the dynamic image from myhost which generates automatically on particular path.

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/<?php echo $_SESSION['PICURL']; ?>" />
```

I am using facebook sharer dialog method and all the tags are working properly, instead of og:image.

I do check on Facebook debuger tool , its showing the following error
og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook.

Comment: If you had an example URL that's not working we could investigate a little more. Or you could file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014271/image-sharing-on-facebook
same problem here, reason unknown